# Gmaps.map.callback is not working properly for adding listener in Gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

My requirement is to add a onclik listener on a marker. 
My view is like below

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
  <div id="map_div" style=" height: 800px;"></div>
</div>

<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script>

handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null } });

var mapOptions = { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE };
handler.buildMap({ provider: mapOptions,  internal: {id: 'map_div'}}, function(){
 markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);

 handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
 handler.fitMapToBounds();
  handler.getMap().setZoom(19);

});



</script>
<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script type="text/javascript">
Gmaps.map.callback = function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < Gmaps.map.markers.length; i++){
    marker = Gmaps.map.markers[i];
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker.serviceObject, 'click',  (function(marker){return function(){alert(marker.id);}})(marker))
 }
}

</script>
<% end %>
```

But when looks like callback function is not getting invoked. Am i missing something here ,or in layout application.html.erb.
In application.html.erb I had put

```
 <%= yield %>
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

My controller code is like below

```
 def index
    @sens = Sen.all
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@sens) do |sen, marker|
marker.lat sen.latitude
marker.lng sen.longitude
marker.picture({"url" =>"/images/red_bl.gif","width" => 36, "height" => 36 })
```

end
   logger.info @hash
  end

rails version is 4.0.2
ruby 1.9.3
'gmaps4rails', '2.1.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gmaps.map.callback` is not an existing method in v2.x.

If you need a callback, simply add it after:

```
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
```

BTW, I recommend you use:

```
marker.getServiceObject()
```

`<%= yield :scripts %>` is not necessary in v2.x

Comment: can you post the documentation link?
I've trouble changing map options after calling Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers